# Argument "statistic" in "tbl_summary" function from "gtsummary" package does not work

Tags: r, summary, gtsummary

I am new to gtsummary package, but when I try to change summary statistics in the tbl_summary function, it gives me error messages, I tried to use the code with different data frames, but the same problem exists.

Here is my code:

```
> data %>% 
+   tbl_summary(statistic = list(
+       all_continuous() ~  "{mean} ({sd})",
+       all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({P}%)"
+       ))
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `tbl_stats = pmap(...)`.
Caused by error in `pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `value[[3L]]()`:
! There was an error assembling the summary statistics for 'age'
  with summary type 'categorical'.

There are 2 common sources for this error.
1. You have requested summary statistics meant for continuous
   variables for a variable being as summarized as categorical.
   To change the summary type to continuous, add the argument
  `type = list(age ~ 'continuous')`
2. One of the functions or statistics from the `statistic=` argument is not valid.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `tbl_stats = pmap(...)`.
Caused by error in `pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `value[[3L]]()`:
! There was an error assembling the summary statistics for 'age'
  with summary type 'categorical'.

There are 2 common sources for this error.
1. You have requested summary statistics meant for continuous
   variables for a variable being as summarized as categorical.
   To change the summary type to continuous, add the argument
  `type = list(age ~ 'continuous')`
2. One of the functions or statistics from the `statistic=` argument is not valid.
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─data %>% ...
  2. ├─gtsummary::tbl_summary(...)
  3. │ └─... %>% ...
  4. ├─dplyr::select(., "variable", "var_type", "var_label", everything())
  5. ├─tidyr::unnest(., "tbl_stats")
  6. ├─dplyr::select(., var_type = "summary_type", "var_label", "tbl_stats")
  7. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
  8. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
  9. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
 10. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 11. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
 12. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
 13. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
 14. └─purrr::pmap(...)
 15.   └─purrr:::pmap_("list", .l, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
 16.     ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
 17.     │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 18.     ├─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
 19.     └─gtsummary (local) .f(...)
 20.       └─gtsummary:::df_stats_to_tbl(...)
 21.         └─base::tryCatch(...)
 22.           └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 23.             └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 24.               └─value[[3L]](cond)
 25.                 └─base::stop(...)
> summary(data)
      age            year              gender           residence        
 Min.   :17.00   Length:373         Length:373         Length:373        
 1st Qu.:18.00   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Median :18.00   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :18.67                                                           
 3rd Qu.:19.00                                                           
 Max.   :30.00                                                           
> data
# A tibble: 373 × 4
     age year     gender residence          
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>              
 1    18 1st year Male   Rural (Countryside)
 2    19 1st year Female Rural (Countryside)
 3    18 1st year Male   Urban (City)       
 4    18 1st year Female Urban (City)       
 5    18 1st year Female Urban (City)       
 6    18 1st year Female Urban (City)       
 7    17 1st year Female Rural (Countryside)
 8    19 2nd year Female Urban (City)       
 9    21 2nd year Male   Urban (City)       
10    18 1st year Male   Rural (Countryside)
# ℹ 363 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

It tells me that age is a categorical variable, but it is a continuous variable, even after removing age, it will give me similar errors with other variables in my data.

I will be happy if someone know how I can fix this, thanks!

Comment: For your age "error", I think the error message is incredibly informative as to your next steps for debugging. It even tells you to add the argument `type = list(age ~ 'continuous')`. Regarding your categorical variable, big `"P"` is not a summary stat you can use: you probably meant to use little `"p"`

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg
Thank you very much!!
yes, it is big P which was the problem.
I spent the whole day reading the code and didn't even notice that!